# Why does a matrix have determinant zero if one row is the sum of two other rows?

Tags: matrices, determinant

So basically here I am trying to understand why it is like that?

Suppose Matrix $$
A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
a+d & b+e & c+f \end{array} \right)
$$

Then, $\det (A) = 0$. 
Why is that? I have tried with subtraction as well and I get $\det (A) = 0$ as well.
I am seeing a pattern, but I cannot explain in strict mathematical terms.

Comment: Do you know *your* definition of determinant? What definition are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "your" definition? Isn't their a common definition of determinant? 
The one I use is: For any 2x2 matrix the determinant is ad-bc and it's inverse only exists if Det A is not equal to zero.

Comment: In fact there are several ways to define determinant, there isn't one standard approach. You can't define something 'by example'. What determinant properties do you have at your disposal?

Comment: There are many ways to define the determinant. You have only defined it for $2\times2$ matrices. Do you know that if you subtract one row from another, it does not change the determinant? Do you know that if you have a row of all zeros, then the determinant is zero?

Comment: Please change the title, the present one asks to show that a row has determinant zero...

Comment: Title still absurd.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest that you answer the questions in my comment. As for a title, I would suggest, "Why does a matrix have determinant zero if one row is the sum of two other rows?"

Comment: Yes I know the stuff about what you asked.

Comment: Good. So, subtract the 1st row from the 3rd row --- doesn't change the determinant --- subtract the 2nd row from the 3rd row --- doesn't change the determinant ---- now there's a row of all zeros --- voila!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two properties of determinants which I assume you know:

(1) You can add/subtract two rows and determinant doesn't change.
(2) If you multiply $k^{th}$ row by a constant, the determinant will be multiplied by the same constant.

Suppose that the matrix $A$ has a row, say $k^{th}$ row, equal to sum of two other rows. Use law (1) and subtract those two rows from $k^{th}$ row. You have a matrix with one row equal to zero. Let the determinant of this matrix be equal to $x$. According to (2), when you multiply the $k^{th}$ row by $2$, the determinant of the new matrix equals $2x$, however your matrix is the same. So, $x=2x$, which means $x=0$.

PS. See [this](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~msapir/msapir/proofdet2.html), too.

Comment: You could have as well multiplied the last row by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that line $k$ is the sum of lines $i$ and $j$ and consider the vector $x$ whose $i$ and $j$ entries are $-1$, entry $k$ is $+2$ and every other entry is $0$.

Then $A^Tx=0$ (*can you show this?*) and $x\ne0$ hence $A^T$ is not invertible, which implies that $\det(A^T)=0$. Since $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$ (*can you show this?*), this shows that $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: I can't show it for those you asked for. Can you kindly elaborate?

Comment: You cannot compute $A^Tx$? To get you started, you might want to tell us what the first entry of $A^Tx$ is.

Comment: Well I have not studied about that concept. So I am not sure what you are asking me to do. But I loved to know more about it.
I am in year 9, which is why this is a bit top of my head.

Comment: You do not know what is $A^Tx$?

Comment: Nope. As stated I have not studied about that concept. Basically right now in my holidays I am looking at some interesting stuff about matrices and exploring about determinants which has made me curious.

Comment: But $A^Tx$ only requires to know what a matrix *is*... Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Rows in a matrix represent transforms of horizontal unit vectors.  So if your matrix represents a transform $T$, then:

$$T([1, 0, 0]) = [a, b, c]$$
$$T([0, 1, 0]) = [d, e, f]$$
$$T([0, 0, 1]) = [a+d, b+e, c+f]$$

Notice that those 3 points plus the origin are co-planar (all four points are in the same plane).  This means that transform $T$ maps the points of a cube into some flat 2D shape.

A determinant tells you how much multidimensional volume you gain or lose from a transform.  For example, determinant of $1\over 2$ means the transformed shape has half the volume of the original.  A 2D shape has zero 3D volume, so we expect the determinant of the example matrix to be zero.  And if you work out the algebra from the definitions, it does.

Comment: Why *unit* vectors?

Comment: I don't understand exactly, is that possibly a rhetorical question?  This is the (transpose of the) way that matrices are constructed from linear transforms of unit axis vectors.  Are you asking me to show how unit vectors are used to construct matrices?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood --- I get what you're saying now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple fact $det(A)=0$ if and only if $A$ is not invertable.

Since last row is sum of first two rows, If you make ths matrice row reduced then you ill get a matrix has $0$ in one row. And you can easily say that this matrix is not invertable so we are done.

Answer (score 0):

One of the rows of $A$ is a linear combination of the others. This means that $A$ is not an invertible matrix and hence its determinant is zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$|A| = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
a+d & b+e & c+f \end{array} \right|$$
there is this property where you can split determinants ([How?](http://www.vitutor.com/alg/determinants/properties_determinants.html) refer clause 7). So,
$$|A| = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
a & b & c \end{array} \right|+\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
d & e & f \end{array} \right| ...(1)$$
Next use the property where determinants with same rows have their $determinant=0$ ([How?](http://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math3260/det2.pdf) refer Corollary 161 page 69) thus,
$$
|A| =0$$
And yeah I think this $2^{nd} $ link will be very useful for you in your future study.